# Is there a way to install lo-menubar as per-user local extension?

Tags: unity, libreoffice, appmenu, extension

I'm using multiple LibreOffice profiles; one for normal work, second for some pseudoheadless automation with vncserver and macros, like:

```
soffice -calc -env':UserInstallation=$SYSUSERCONFIG/'$DIR'/openoffice.org' "macro:///Standard.Module1.SaveResult(\"file://$OUTFILE\")"
```

It's incredible useful. What's more, I can peek at the current progress with vncviewer any time.

Installing lo-menubar package causes the running second profile try to use Unity's globalmenu, which breaks the whole magic. Is there a way to use lo-menubar as a normal per-user (pre-configurationdir) extension?

Answer (score 2):

Per Jan's own comment:

> Oh, just figured it out:
>   `sudo apt-get install lo-menubar
>   unopkg add -v /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/menubar
>   sudo apt-get purge lo-menubar`
>   This install's the extension for profile one (default) only.
>   (I obviously can't answer my own question within 8 hours because I'm new user here :( )